# C++ Replacing non-alpha/apostrophe with spaces in a string

Tags: string, c++11, replace

I am reading in a text file and parsing the words into a map to count numbers of occurrences of each word on each line. I am required to ignore all non-alphabetic chars (punctuation, digits, white space, etc) except for apostrophes. I can figure out how to delete all of these characters using the following code, but that causes incorrect words, like "one-two" comes out as "onetwo", which should be two words, "one" and "two".

Instead, I am trying to now replace all of these values with spaces instead of simply deleting, but can't figure out how to do this. I figured the replace-if algorithm would be a good algorithm to use, but can't figure out the proper syntax to accomplish this. C++11 is fine. Any suggestions?

Sample output would be the following:

```
"first second" = "first" and "second"
"one-two" = "one" and  "two"
"last.First" = "last" and "first"
"you're" = "you're"
"great! A" = "great" and "A"

// What I initially used to delete non-alpha and white space (apostrophe's not working currently, though)

// Read file one line at a time
while (getline(text, line)){
    istringstream iss(line);            
    // Parse line on white space, storing values into tokens map
    while (iss >> word){
        word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), my_predicate), word.end());
        ++tokens[word][linenum];
    }
    ++linenum;
}

bool my_predicate(char c){
    return c == '\'' || !isalpha(c); // This line's not working properly for apostrophe's yet
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool my_predicate(char c){
    return c == '\'' || !isalpha(c);
}
```

Here you're writing that you want to remove the char if **it is** and apostrophe or if **it is not** an alphabetical character.

Since you want to replace these, you should use [`std::replace_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) :

```
std::replace_if(std::begin(word), std::end(word), my_predicate, ' ');
```

And you should correct your predicate too :

```
return !isalpha(c) && c != '\'';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) to pre-process the input line before sending it to the istringstream. This will also simplify your inner loop.

```
while (getline(text, line)){
    replace_if(line.begin(), line.end(), my_predicate, ' ');
    istringstream iss(line);            
    // Parse line on white space, storing values into tokens map
    while (iss >> word){
        ++tokens[word][linenum];
    }
    ++linenum;
}
```